# How to decrease addEvent delay in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser.io

I'm making a simple game. I want my 'enemies' to fall from the top of the screen:

```
    const enemies = this.physics.add.group();

    function enemyGen(){
      const xCoord = Math.random()*gameState.w;
      enemies.create(xCoord, 10, 'enemy');
    }

    const enemyGenLoop = this.time.addEvent({
      callback: enemyGen,
      delay: ......,
      callbackScope: this,
      loop: true
    })
```

I would like to decrease the delay when a player reach a certain score (which is stored in gameState.score).

I was thinking about having a variable stored in gameState.delay and then updating it from update(). The problem is that even if the gameState.delay is changed the addEvent still uses the previous value of gameState.delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the ***addEvent delay*** into a variable & set it to another value afterwards like so:

- **First**, store the ***addEvent delay*** into a variable.

```
delayTimer = this.time.addEvent({
    delay: 2000,
    callback: ()=>{
        // calls a function here
    },
    loop: true
})
```

- **Second**, set the delay option to another value.

```
delayTimer.delay = 1000;
```